# I18n Internationalization for Regex honorific checking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, internationalization

I'd like to store a list of honorifics for many languages which I need to check against with regex.  I'd like to store it just like you would with any other Internationalization in the local translation load path in YAML.

Here's the two honorific lists I'll use for English

```
/(?:Dr|Mr|Mrs|Ms|Miss|Sir|Dr|Prof|Br|Sr|Fr|Rev|Pr)[\.:]?/i
/(?:Doctor|Professor|Brother|Sister|Father|Reverend|Pastor)/i
```

I'm only familiar with text sentances being stored in the translation files.  How can I save lists and use it with the regex matcher?  Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**config/locales/en.yml**

```
en:
  honorifics:
    short: '(?:Dr|Mr|Mrs|Ms|Miss|Sir|Dr|Prof|Br|Sr|Fr|Rev|Pr)[\.:]?'
    long: '(?:Doctor|Professor|Brother|Sister|Father|Reverend|Pastor)'
```

Example usage:

```
"Mr. Apple Dumpling".scan /\A#{I18n.t 'honorifics.short'}/iu
```

And it works.  It outputs:

```
 => ["Mr."]
```